# iOS - where does the push notification dialog reference the app name from

Tags: iphone, ios, apple-push-notifications

I want to change the name of my app printed on the dialog prompting the user to receive push notifications - "Myapp would like to send you push notifications". I want to change Myapp to something else. I tried changing my project name, but it did not work. Where is that name referenced from?

Comment: Maybe you need to check Bundle display name on Info.plist

Comment: that worked! if you want to make it an answer I'd accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you need to check Bundle display name on Info.plist.